# Отобразить Dropdown в Navbar

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap4

Не отображается Dropdown в Navbar, пример брал готового шаблона bootstrap, там всё отображается нормально, но у меня после нескольких нажатий на стрелочку перестаёт отображаться dropdown, это же происходит если я нажал мышкой на другую область navbar, в чём проблема?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('redir') }}">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      @guest
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a></li>
      @else
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('users.editprofile') }}">{{__('Edit Profile')}}</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" style="color: red" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" >{{__('Logout')}}</a>
        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      @endguest
    </ul>
    <a class="nav-link" style="color: white;">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: dropdown реализован с помощью js. Смотрите в эту сторону. Может не в том порядке подклчаете. Или не то подключаете. и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему удалив ссылку с asset на app.js, видимо он работал только со стандартным dropdown, который входит в base.balde шаблон для Laravel.